# Sonar cannot cover branches calling to Exception throwing function

Tags: java, junit4, sonarqube, jacoco

I am writing code coverage for my project and experiencing a weird behavior. I have a function like this

```
public void testException(int i) throws Exception {
    if (i == 0) {
        throw new Exception("exception");
    }
}
```

and the test case

```
@Test
public void testException() {
    try {
        mapper.testException(0);
        fail("Wrong");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        assertEquals("exception", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

After running test case through maven (`mvn sonar:sonar`), then the branch is covered in Sonar. However, if the tested function is like this

```
public void testException(int i) throws Exception {
    if (i == 0) {
        throwException();
    }
}

public void throwException() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("exception");
}
```

then the `if` branch is not covered, though the inner of `throwException` function is actually executed. Is there anyway to overcome this problem? I need to cover 100% of the class

Answer (score 1):

Look like the reason why code is not covered is in the [FAQ](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/faq.html)

> **Code with exceptions shows no coverage. Why?**
>
> JaCoCo determines code execution with so called probes. Probes are
>   inserted into the control flow at certain positions. Code is
>   considered as executed when a subsequent probe has been executed. In
>   case of exceptions such a sequence of instructions is aborted
>   somewhere in the middle and not marked as executed.

Still i don't understand why the coverage of the direct throw still appears on sonar

Comment: Which version of SonarQube are you using?

Comment: @CSchulz: I used both 4.2 and 4.5